# sed replace string with & symbol failed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a json file, want to replace a placeholder with a new value.

Given that new value have & symbol, it return wrong result.

```
export uri='mongodb+srv://user:password@dbname.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Original:

```
{
  "db_uri": "#uri#"
}
```

Wanted:

```
{
  "db_uri": "mongodb+srv://user:password@dbname.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

By running

```
sed -e "s|#uri#|$uri|g" file.json
```

But it actually return

```
"mongodb+srv://user:password@dbname.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true#uri#w=majority"
```

The & symbol in original uri become #uri#

is there any way to fix without editing the uri itself?

Comment: Could you please do let us know if this is a json file?

Comment: WIth sed 4.4 it works with any issue.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It says at the top that it's a JSON file indeed.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 mentioned two times in the body

Comment: Core point from duplicate: use `${uri//&/\\&}`

Comment: @BenjaminW. that's exactly what I want! Thanks.

Comment: To RavinderSingh13's point, since this is JSON, you might get a more robust / generally applicable solution using jq.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Actually the use case is a part of deployment, replace the json by linux cli. It has the limitation without using sed. Btw, I will look for any better solution instead.